# Select row with concat, group, and limit using RAND()

Tags: mysql

I have a table `tbl_` question. I want record like this:

```
subject_id question_id
3              4,5
```

My table looks like this:

```
id question subject_id 
1    a          1
2    b          1
3    c          2
4    d          3
5    e          3
6    f          3
```

I have tried using

```
SELECT subject_id, group_concat(id) 
FROM tbl_qus_bank 
WHERE subject_id=3  
ORDER by RAND() LIMIT 2
```

but it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

Try a subquery:

```
SELECT subject_id, group_concat(id) 
FROM (SELECT qb.*
      FROM tbl_qus_bank qb
      WHERE subject_id = 3  
      ORDER by RAND() LIMIT 2 
     ) qb
GROUP BY subject_id;
```

Or, alternatively, you can use `substring_index()` -- if the total number of subjects is not too large:

```
SELECT subject_id,
       substring_index(group_concat(id) order by rand(), ',', 2)
FROM tbl_qus_bank 
WHERE subject_id = 3;
```

`ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` apply to the results of the entire query.  That is, they are processed *after* the `GROUP_CONCAT()` has already generated its results.